# Unable to access "Volume 914 GB" while mounting a drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs, drive

[ubuntu mount error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOzhd.png):

> **Unable to access "Volume 914 GB"**
>
> Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sda4: Command-line `mount
> "/mnt/sda4"` exited with non-zero exit status 12: Failed to read last
> sector (1946409837): Invalid argument
>  HINTS: Either the volume is
> a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
>   or it was not setup correctly
> (e.g. by not using mdadm --build...),
>    or a wrong device is tried
> to be mounted,
>  or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS), 
>  or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid 
> Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Invalid argument 
> The device '/dev/sda4' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
>  Maybe the
> wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
> partition (e.g. dev/sda not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?

I have an SSD and an HDD drive on my computer. I installed Ubuntu on SSD. When I tried to mount the HDD I got the above error.

I tried several terminal lines which I found around here, but they did not work. I also tried to add ***,ro*** line in disk utility, but that did not work either.

I am seeking a solution that does not include formatting my HDD and losing everything.

Comment: lots of questions here... I can only assume that sda is your hard drive and sda4 is where the windows partition is.?? how old is the computer .. is this MBR or EFI boot? What is your purpose of trying to mount it? Is this a attempt at dual boot and now you only have Ubuntu available... if so .. did you try running `sudo update-grub` and see if it finds your install of windows and adds a menu item for it.

Comment: «I don't want to format my HDD and lose everything» Understandable. That's why you should [recover your data as written here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283009/84179) before formatting. ;)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY
```

where XY is the name of the drive 
for example sda4

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.